# Receiving mysqli parameter warnings?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm a beginner at PHP and I'm attempting to create a register, login form. There's a problem I've been trying to solve for a few days and I'm not sure where I went wrong, I'm hoping I can find the solution to it and understand what I did wrong.

**My errors:**

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /registration.php on line 64

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /registration.php on line 66

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /registration.php on line 73
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostname.com","user998988","9858588");
mysqli_select_db($connection,"user9898989");

   if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {

    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $user_email = $_POST['email'];

   if($user_name==''){
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter your name!')</script>";
   exit();
   }

   if($user_pass==''){
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter your password!')</script>";
   exit();
   }

   if($user_email==''){
   echo "<script>alert('Please enter your email!')</script>";
   exit();
   }

   $check_email = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";

   $run = mysqli_query($check_email);

   if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0) {

   echo "<script>alert('Email $user_email already exists')</script>";
   exit();
   }

   $querying = "insert into users (user_name,user_pass,user_email) values ('$user_name','$user_pass','$user_email')";
   if(mysqli_query($querying)) {

   echo  "<script>alert('Registration successful!')</script>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear what is wrong I would say...

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*()` and `mysqli_*()`. They're different and you can't mix them. Don't use `mysql_*()` - it's deprecated. Beyond that, the message tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for my idiotic question and thank everyone for pointing out my flaws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read the comments above, they are correct:

You need to pass the connection on the first parameter of `mysqli_query`:

```
$run = mysqli_query($connection, $check_email);
```

Then after that, don't mix up API, you're using mysqli, then use the appropriate function:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) {
```

And lastly, always try to use prepared statments, you're using mysqli anyways:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name,user_pass,user_email) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $user_name, $user_pass, $user_email);
$stmt->execute();
```

And I suggest don't insert plain naked password in DB. Use the [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$check_email = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";

   $run = mysqli_query($check_email);

   if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)
```

**Change above line to this**

```
$check_email = "select * from users where user_email='$user_email'";

   $run = mysqli_query($connection,$check_email);

   if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)
```

**and remove this line**

```
mysqli_select_db($connection,"user9898989");
```